# CSV or Mysql for static data?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, angularjs

We are building a website which uses a some static data like "countries, cities related to each country, mountains and so on".

My friends suggest that its faster to store them in a CSV file and import them using javascript. He says its faster than gettings them from mysql.

Me on the want to stick with mysql so that we have everything in one place. I dont think that 0.00001 sec really matters.

Can you help us?
When should we use mysql and when csv?

- we are talking about static data. We wont change them in future
- The website we are building is in php, angularjs

Comment: That really depends for what you are going to use it. For static data it would be better to have them not stored in the database to decrease load on the database server and increase the speed of your application.

Comment: If you store it in the database, you can use foreign keys to enforce data validity. If you don't, you need to come up with alternative solutions for that.

Comment: In addition to foreign keys if in the database, you can also use joins in your sql queries

Comment: What does "import them using javascript" mean?  Is this client side scripting?  Doesn't seem that the alternatives that you are comparing are parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For static data of that kind the only real incentive for using MySQL (that I can think of) is for database validation. I'd suggest just going with the CSV, particularly if you're not planning to change it.

Answer (score 3):

Faster might not be the best criterion for deciding what to do.

I'll bet your friend has no data to support or refute either recommendation.

Isn't a JavaScript import a network hop, just like a call to the database?

I'd compromise: put them in MySQL, load them into memory on startup, and cache them in the middle tier.  You'll only pay for the network hop to GET them from the middle tier to the browser and the data will be in a real database.

If you don't have a middle tier, then you're out of luck.

Does every user need all the values in that table, or just a few?  Why force every user to accept a big download?

Comment: Every user needs those data to browse the site.

Comment: Another info: He just told me that csv is simpler to import into a js array. Our site shall use a live search over all the data. For example if you type: fuji then the fuji mountain, fuji city, and Japan appar as hints

Comment: Sounds like ajax, which would be better for you than trying to preload all of this.  @duffymo is right - put it in the database, cache it, and then access it via ajax.

Comment: Nonsense.  Your friend has more opinions than knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

In general, predictable files in predictable locations are much faster than DB Lookups.  DB is Find/Locate, pull from Disk, Deliver.  File is where you want it to be and no look ups involved.

Many caching techniques will store content to a DB for administrative purposes, but the content of the entry is also written to file for quick lookup when needed.

You may want to consider a hybrid of both.  DB management, and file caching.  You'll get the best of both worlds, and build a platform for later use beyond State list management.

There are a number of caching techniques, and approaches.  For example, I deploy on demand caching.  If the file is not located where I expect, I cache from the DB into a file dynamically written on demand.  When the DB Entry is updated, kill the cached file.  Subsequently the file is written when it is requested on demand.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving data from a CSV may be faster, but it doesn't give you referential integrity. If you're saying something like

```
users ( 
    country_id,
    locale_id, ...
)
```

If you want you can cache that data in a CSV, but duplicate it in the DB so you can have some referential integrity. That way when you query the data all of the fields with info about that country or whatever will come back with whatever record is meant to join it. That way you get the benefit of caching it and retrieving it from a faster data store without losing referential integrity.

Answer (score 1):

Using MySQL to store countries is a good idea in my opinion because this let you ensure data consistency through foreign keys.

Speed is not very important in such cases because you deal with few data (several hundreds rows).

Keep in mind that storing such data outside of the database will probably increase significantly the complexity of your application.

Hope this helps ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use SQLite ? Its got some benefits of both CSV and MySQL

Comment: SQL Lite's not going to be much faster than MySQL for retrieving data because it still has to go to disk to get it and still has to parse queries to retrieve the data... Also SQLite employs a very pessimistic locking strategy compared to an innodb table, so concurrency will become a problem if there's ever an update.

Comment: Pretty much anything is going to have to go to the disk at some point, If caching is working correctly it will hardly ever hit the disk (assuming its loaded on a fair number of pages). SQLite keeps the data easy to maintain (in comparison to CSV). If its really not likely to change you can use the Archive table in MySQL.
also PHP has to parse the CSV file.

Comment: Op's saying he'd have javascript fetch the CSV, so PHP wouldn't have to parse it (Just the client).... Serving static content from apache will be faster every time than serving that same content through a PHP script. Also regardless it's most definitely faster to tokenize a CSV than it is to open a SQLite connection (if you need the entire CSV).